# How to run multiple job in parallel in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, yaml

I am using yaml file processing with spark and code is written in java

Example: Suppose we have 5 yaml files 1.yaml, 2.yaml, 3.yaml, 4.yaml, 5.yaml

1: The first 4 yaml file execution is independent of each other, so wanted to run those in parallel
2: 5.yaml file requires the output generated by first 4 yaml file processing, so 5.yaml file processing should wait until first 4 completed

Given that:
Spark cluster is used by many application for processing

Consideration:
1: Each application should get resource allocation fairly, means if some jobs are longer running and more resource intensive then other applications have to wait,so this should not happen i.e. resource allocation should be limited for a application

Comment: Look into the use of `apache airflow` to run your jobs. You can configure the jobs to have dependencies and trigger only after the first 4 have run.

Comment: For equal use of cluster resources, try and size your jobs to get the right size executors and memory. Also consider Spark's `dynamic resource allocation` if you want this to be managed by Spark.